# Sending a paper which is under review for showing competency in order to find a paid sabbatical leave

Tags: publications, job-search, sabbatical

I am a Ph.D. student. I submitted my paper to a highly prestigious journal and also answered with a very detailed and long answer to a reject & resubmit type of revise to this journal. I think it took a long time for the journal and its referees to read and decide.

At the same time, I have a very severe financial condition as my source of finance, cuts my salary since my Ph.D. got longer than their standard duration for a Ph.D. I want to find a paid sabbatical leave. I decided to send my papers to many people in order to find such a one year job. I want to know is it a good idea to send my last submission to this journal without telling the name of the journal to through email to obtain a paid sabbatical leave which I think is rare.

What's your advice for me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you on a visa? Are you allowed by your visa to take time off? Will your institution allow you to take a leave of absence—note that students technically do not have sabbaticals.

Comment: Can PhD students take sabbaticals?

Comment: So, what you want to do is take a year off from your studies and get a non-academic job to earn some money?  That's a reasonable thing to want to do, but please don't call it a "paid sabbatical leave" - that's very confusing.  "Sabbatical" is a very specific process that's normally reserved to faculty, and when you add "paid" it makes it sound like you want to be paid by your home university.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "sabbatical" - as @NateEldredge has pointed out, it is not clear what you think it means

Comment: I don't know the exact meaning of the term "sabbatical". What I mean by this is to do a research work on my thesis on a different university and of course in different country.

Comment: No, I am in my home country.

Comment: Please note that you should consult your own university to see if they will allow you to return to complete your PhD after your year away. Likewise, if you are applying for jobs elsewhere, you should make it clear that you wish to go back to your PhD afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, most hiring managers or hiring faculty have a specific background or skill set in mind for a particular open position, this is doubly so for a short-term position (no time for on-the-job training). From that perspective, they will likely already have made their mind up about you by the time they finish a cover letter and a CV. Overwhelming them with extraneous information, such as providing them with a 10+ page draft manuscript, is actually more likely to **damage** your chances of being hired, compared with a well-thought-out cover letter and a clear CV.

You should feel free to discuss the manuscript in your cover letter  by providing a succinct summary of the work and its context, particularly if you think it has the chance of being published in a prestigious journal (i.e. it exemplifies the quality of work you could be expected to produce in your hypothetical paid position). I would also list it on my CV: in my field (engineering), students listing manuscripts that aren't yet published in their publication list is generally standard practice. Just make sure to label clearly as "manuscript in preparation," and **don't** list the journal it is submitted to, since this is meaningless unless the paper is actually accepted, i.e.:

- Author A, Author B,..., "Title," *manuscript in preparation* (2018).

Comment: Since the OP has accepted your answer, it should be pointed out that he or she seems to be asking for something more than just "how do I present a good job application". He or she is under the impression that one can go and work at a different university _while still keeping the option of completing their PhD_

Comment: I think almost any university would let a student put their degree "on hold" while they deal with financial or personal hardships. There are also lots of paid internships at companies for graduate students - i.e. spending a summer or even a year at a company doing work that may or may not end up as part of the thesis. Therefore, the crux of the OP's question isn't "can I do this" but "how do I do this."

Comment: In which country/system? I happen to know that UK system differs from Canadian, for instance

Comment: sorry, you're right that this could vary by country or discipline - my experience is with US physics/engineering programs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with paid sabbaticals for students. They are normally granted to tenured academics, at least in my experience. But for any sort of leave from your studies, I don't think there is any issue about revealing your "work in progress" to potential employers. Since it is under review you might be interfering with the blind review process but that is really for the editor to manage. The work is yours until you give up copyright to a journal.

But, you should check the policies of the journal. It may be that in submitting, you are implicitly agreeing not to share the work during the review process. If that is the case, however, your option would be to withdraw the paper.

It is also possible that you would consider asking this question of the journal editor and ask for advice there. It might nudge the editor to make a decision, whether favorable or unfavorable.

But prior to publishing the work, it is best to label it as "in progress."

Comment: I would call it a “leave of absence.”

Comment: Also, I believe that most journal policies are designed to preclude duplicate publication. Privately distributing a draft manuscript for feedback should be something journals would not want to prevent. But as we’ve all noted, journals can have very different and at times seemingly crazy policies.